# Android SoftKeyboard Sample project wrong width on Nougat

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-softkeyboard, android-7.0-nougat

I got the Android SoftKeyboard from here:

```
https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SoftKeyboard
```

Built and run the app with Android Studio. This is what I get on the Nexus 5 API 25 Emulator:

[image]

When I run it on the Nexus 4 API 23 Emulator it looks correct:

[image]

Anyone knows what might be going on here and why the width is wrong in the first screenshot?

UPDATE: Same simulator using API level 25 and 24 results in screenshot 1. API level 23 and below don't have this problem. Wonder if the APIs have changed or is a bug in the SDK...